# Create dependent drop lists (using data validation or combo box) with auto refresh

Tags: excel

I want to create many dependent drop list (more than 100) that auto refresh when the source list changes.
I am able to auto update the list using data validation and by changing the source list using named ranges but the selected item doesn't change unless I re-select the data validation list.

lets take as a simplified example the following:

**category_List:**

colors = {black, red, green}
languages = {english, french, spanish}

So if i select colors, i want to display the colors list and if I select the languages then I want to select the languages list. If red was selected then when i change to languages category, I want the french to be automatically selected and so on.

I am aware of two solutions:

1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWasYHG1lmM&list=PLmHVyfmcRKywYhC1Q9eZqR7D-_cdiwl6y&index=12
Uses VBA to do that, but since I have more than 100 list and the dependent list are random then I have to manually change each list when a specific source list changed. I dont think this the best idea.

2)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSPtWo3IiOM&list=PLmHVyfmcRKywYhC1Q9eZqR7D-_cdiwl6y&index=11
A better approach as this will automatically change the selection when the category changes and it also give an additional feature which is the linked cell that gives a bi-directional connection between the cell and the combo box.
But my issue is that linked cell returns a 1-based index and I want that to be 0-based index. So if I select the first element, I want the linked cell to display 0 not 1 and vice versa...

Is there a way to achieve what I want easily ? either using one of the proposed approach or using another one ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you want something like this.

Create 2 comboboxes on your sheet.
In VBA make the following code:

```
Sub PopulateComboBox_Category()

    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    With Blad1
        N = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    With Blad1.ComboBox2
        .Clear
        For i = 1 To N
            .AddItem Blad1.Cells(1, i).Value
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
Sub PopulateCombobox()

    Dim Targetcell As Range
    Dim strCategory As String

    strCategory = Blad1.ComboBox2.Value
    Set Targetcell = Range("1:1").Find(What:=strCategory)
    Dim col As Long
    col = Targetcell.Column


    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    With Blad1
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With Blad1.ComboBox1
        .Clear
        For i = 2 To N
            .AddItem Blad1.Cells(i, col).Value
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Make a change event on the sheet with the following code.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
Call PopulateCombobox
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you too much for your answer, That is not actually the main issue (even though it will help me later to automate the combo box creations). Assuming I want to create  them manually, I would need to change link cell to return 0-based index and not 1-based index... So if my Linked cell is A1 then when i select the first element in the combo box, i need A1 to display 0 and if put 0 in A1, I need combo box to select the first element.

I have already a solution to change the source list of the combo box by changing the list of the list in the named range.